# Prove the existence of infinitely many numbers of a specific form

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, prime-factorization

I know that this may seem an easy/noob question. Sorry if you also think that.

As a math enthusiast, I have spent some hours looking for different proofs of the infinitude of prime numbers. Most of them (almost all) use the fact that every single integer has a unique prime factorization (Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic) or, at least, that is a product of primes. However, I have not been able to find any proof that did not use that.

Then, this is what I am looking for. Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that $0 \le f(x) <x$. Also, let $p$ represent a prime number greater that $2$ and $m>0$ any arbitray integer.

Which ways are there to prove that there are infinitely many numbers that are not of the form $pm+f(p)$ for any prime $p>2$ without taking into account the fact that there are infinitely many primes?

I know that this "conjecture" would imply their infinitude. What I am asking  for is a proof that does not contain the sentence "...and, as we already know that there are infinitely many prime numbers...". My problem when analyzing this problem is that we cannot "copy/paste" proofs of the infinitude of primes since here we cannot use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic because of the addition.

Thank you.

*Edit 1*: we can make a basic heuristic to calculate the amount of these integer lower or equal than another given $x$.

$$ \# a  \{a\not = pn+f(p); a \le x\} \sim x \prod_{p\le x} \frac{p-1}{p} =O \left ( \frac{x}{\log(x)} \right )$$

*Edit 2*: what is it known about the case $f(p)$ being a constant greater than $0$?

Comment: I can't think  off-hand of any proofs of the infinitude of prime numbers which do rely on the FTA.

Comment: There's a proof using only that every integer but $\;-1,\,1\;$ is a multiple of primes, but it requires some basic knowledge of topology.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have read it and it uses the FTA when taking the union of all the arithmetic progressions $S(p,0)$. I have also tried to apply that model to prove the existence of infinitely many numbers that are not of the form $pm+\frac{p--1}{2}$, and did not succeed.

Comment: @user3141592 No, it doesn't. It only uses, as mentioned, only the fact that every integer but $\;\pm1\;$  is the product of primes (which, btw, can be proved by and argument of infinite descend), without uniqueness.

Comment: I second the comment of Lord Shark the Unknown.  Euclid's proof doesn't rely on FTA, nor Euler's, nor the topological one already mentioned.  All that is involved is really the definition of prime.  A number is either itself prime or divisible by some prime.  Wait -- I guess Euler's does use FTA!

Comment: Well, that's true, thanks. I mixed both concepts

Comment: Can $m$ be negative?

Comment: @Algorithms No, corrected. Thanks

Comment: Can $m=0$, or is $m$ positive integers only?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Positive integers only

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/collmathj.48.issue-3

You may go to this link to find 4 latest proofs of infinitude of primes.

Comment: @Arpan Thank you, but I do not have free access to that site

Comment: @Arpan are those proofs the ones described here? https://www.google.es/amp/s/northshieldsite.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/some-new-proofs-of-the-infinitude-of-primes/amp/

Comment: yes two of them are there, two of them are mine...although they are easy

Comment: @Arpan well, the problem here is the same that the problem with other famous proofs: they use the fact that any integer $n$ has prime factor, which can't be used to prove the infinity of numbers that are not of the form $pn+f(p)$ because of the addition

Comment: See it's a very fundamental and basic fact, just think that you dont want to use that, then how will you proceed?
You just know that a prime is a number which has no divisor, the fact that any integer n has prime factor gets automatically invoked here when you are talking of divisors, basically, it is a sort of definition of primes and you are bound to use it.

Comment: @Arpan Can't we use some kind of modified Eratosthenes Sieve?

Comment: Or, even better, Sundaram's Sieve